# how to search multiple tables with one text field in c#

Tags: c#, split, textbox

i have Access data base..
want to search 4 tables from 1 textbox, if desired word not found in table1 then move to table 2 and so on ..if found the word for example in table3 then stop the searching and split word from given instruction show output in textbox like before and after split in 2/3 different text boxes .. can any one help me?

Comment: Can you show some sample data from your table and include whatever relevant code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

put in senquence the list to each table if you found the text digited in textbox then stop your look for and not search in table2, table3 and table4.

I understand that.

Comment: To elaborate on [Syed Talal’s](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34953362/#comment57638520_34953362) point. If you supply a minimal reproducible example to go along with your question we can use that to show you how it might be possible to answer your question––it's more likely that we will be able to help you.  Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).